# Serverless Deploy Pip fails - Manual Pip succeeds

Tags: python, pip, serverless-framework, serverless

I wrote a python Serverless application.

I have a requirements.txt file that looks like:

```
git+https://github.com/Blah1/blah2@1.0#egg=blah3
oauth2==1.9.0.post1
```

When I run `sls deploy` or `sudo sls deploy` it fails saying:

`Command "git clone -q https://github.com/Blah1/blah2.git /tmp/pip-install-jxs9quvp/blah2" failed with error code 128 in None`

I've tried changing to ssh - same error.

I've tried to download it manually - works fine.

I've tried changing the command to use the local files I downloaded and

### depending on the setup:

- Fails with the same `error code 128 in None` error
- Fails with a different error saying it can't find the file even though I verified path and

Comment: I think it breaks, because you are using a `#` symbol. This seems to be used for [checking given hashes](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/468). Does the following work for you? `pip install git+https://github.com/Blah1/blah2@1.0#egg=blah3`

Comment: @feliks thanks for the idea - admittedly no that verbatim doesn't work in the command line. But I have a bunch of other applications that use a similar format in their `requirements.txt` and it works fine. Just for fun I removed the `#egg=blah3` part and it still failed with the same exact error.

Comment: Does `pip install 'git+https://github.com/Blah1/blah2@1.0#egg=blah3'` work then? (Notice the `'`s)

Comment: @feliks, in the command line that does work. In the `requirements.txt` it does not.